# Is it possible to place the ng-switch-when attribute on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I'm trying to switch elements using [`ng-switch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) showing specific elements when I set a certain index.

`ng-switch` is working, except it's only showing the last switch statement.

I'm only showing the "Frame 2" div when using this code:

```
<div ng-switch="frame">
  <div ng-switch-when="1">Frame 1</div>
  <span>Some permanent text</span>
  <span ng-switch-when="2">Text relevant to frame 2</span>
  <div ng-switch-when="2">Frame 2</div>
</div>
```

I want the above to show all `switch-when` when `frame` is set to 2.

**Note**: The markup can't change.

- How can I do this?
- And if I can't is there a better/different alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest your markup:

```
<div ng-switch="frame">
    <div ng-switch-when="1">Frame 1</div>
    <span>Some permanent text</span>
    <div ng-switch-when="2">
        <span>Text relevant to frame 2</span>
        <div>Frame 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit: OP edited his question to specify that the markup cannot change.**

You can't apply the same `ng-switch-when` to multiple elements. You *can* use `ng-show` though:

```
<div>
    <div ng-show="frame == 1">Frame 1</div>
    <span>Some permanent text</span>
    <span ng-show="frame == 2">Text relevant to frame 2</span>
    <div ng-show="frame == 2">Frame 2</div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tqJrL/)</kbd>

Comment: I can't, those elements need to be displayed as is.

Comment: Well unless you modify the behaviour of `ng-switch` this is the only way you'll be able to do it using that directive. Otherwise use `ng-show`.

Comment: Basically what you're saying is `ng-switch` doesn't work like that :( If you point that out in your answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide an alternate solution using `ng-show`.

Comment: Fantastic, that might just do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the nesting mentioned by André Dion is a cleaner solution, but if you need this format you could use ng-if instead. This requires Angular 1.1.5+.

```
<div>
  <div ng-if="frame==1">Frame 1</div>
  <span>Some permanent text</span>
  <span ng-if="frame==2">Text relevant to frame 2</span>
  <div ng-if="frame==2">Frame 2</div>
</div>
```

Docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf

Edit: While ng-show will simply hide the element, ng-if will remove it from the DOM entirely.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to ask what's the difference. I also looked it up in the docs. I just need `ng-show` but this is good for anyone who might run into such a case.

Comment: How do you access the "hidden" element. I typically don't see it on the DOM in web inspector, so I want to be sure if I attempt to access it, that I can modify the hidden ones.